# I can execute main.py without module error in pycharm but in windows cmd I'm facing module not found error and I'm using conda interpreter

Tags: python

> File "E:\nvn\Hacker_rank\Zoom_clone\main.py", line 4, in 
> `from vidstream import *`
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vidstream'

Answer (score 1):

In Pycharm by default you are with in a virtual environment and you would have already installed the specified/dependent module. But that module will only be installed into that virtualenv. So when you are running from command line that module wont be available.
So either you could point to the same virtualenv or you could create a new virtual environment and install the specific module into it and run the code.

Please let me know if it helps.